# How to replace every occurrence of a path in all files withing a directory and its sub-directories

Tags: linux, sed, replace, path, find

I want to replace every occurrence of `/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/` by `/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/` in all files within a directory, here `/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/`, and its sub-directories.

I've tried:

```
find /home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/ \
-path "*/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/*" \
-type f | 
sed -i 's@/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/@/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/@g'
```

but it gives me an error, no files found

also the -exec command apparently does not work on my server and I don't have sudo rights to install anything

Basically I want to do this:

> Search all files in directory `/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/` and its sub-directories, that contain the string (path) `/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/` inside the file

> Substitute all the ocurrences of `/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/` by `/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/` inside the files

Comment: You want to rename files or to text replace filepath in files?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do the filenames have a commonality that occurs only in the filename but not in directory names?

Comment: @gilles-quénot I want to search every ocurrency of $STRING1 inside all files in a specific directory and replace it with $STRING2

The strings being the path "/home/...."

Comment: @cyrus I don't understand exactly what you mean, i want to replace the strings inside all files in a directory

Comment: @RicardoSilvestre: The question was, for example, do the filenames all end in `.txt`?

Comment: hey @cyrus , no, a bunch of different file extensions

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a way of testing this. Normally, I would just leave it as a comment, but it's a bit much for a comment and having it formatted may help understanding what is happening:

```
find /home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/ -type f \
| xargs -I '{}' /bin/grep -l '/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA' {} \
| xargs -I '{}' /bin/sed -i '' 's@/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA/@/home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/@g' {}
```

Depending on your situation, it makes sense to copy all files that will be modified to a "SAVE" directory, so if there are problems, you don't have to try to revert the changes. Test, test, test and don't have to cry later (-; (From experience!)

```
find /home/nxfXXXXX/TestCases/ -type f \
| xargs -I '{}' /bin/grep -l '/home/nxaXXXXX/simulation/MSIP/DPGA' {} \
| xargs -I '{}] /bin/cp '{}' /path/to/backupDir
```

Going back to the firrst code, this lists all regular files (not dirs, links, etc) and passes their names via `xargs` to `grep` which searches for your target string. If that is found, the filename is emitted (by `grep -l`), which is then processed by another `xargs` passing the filenames to an line `sed` script.

If you're not using MacOS, the you can replace `sed -i ''` with just `sed -i`.

I
If it doesn't solve your problem, maybe it gives you some new ideas.

IHTH